# How Clone magento Import/export admin functionality for customer front-end?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How to clone import/export feature from magento admin to customer page?

I want to copy some magento admin features to front-end how do to this in magento way when you create a module?

Comment: I think you are trying to ask for a reference or tool or tutorial. This platform is not for such type of questions. Here you can ask queries related to difficulties in your code.

Comment: You need to read [ask].